# Propel "read-only" mode

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a "read-only" connection in Propel. Basically, I'm going to need to execute a written-by-user request, and I need to be sure he will not break anything.

Of course, I can wrap the request into a transaction (and will do so with no other choice), but I would like to know if Propel has this ability.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a connection like this:

```
$conn = Propel::getConnection(MyClassPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_READ);
```

Then you can use this connection in your query terminators, e.g

```
$book = BookQuery::create()
    ->filterByTitle('some title')
    ->find($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a database user having only the permission to do selects.